RMSE on Individual vs. Aggregate Data
I am comparing two scenarios:

A model is made and predictions obtained on a test set. Then deciles are formed by ordering the prediction and making 10 buckets of equal volume according to a weight.
The average actual value and average prediction within each bucket is found. Then an RMSE is calculated with those averages.

Same thing, but the RMSE is calculated directly on the test data instead of forming deciles.


Then these metrics are used to compare model performance. Using the aggregation method provides very different results on a relative basis between models and I want to understand why.
The type of model is a tweedie regression, for insurance premium modelling.

Welcome to Cross Validated! Why are you using this alternative technique of calculating something RMSE-y?

When you calculate the usual RMSE, you get a sense of how close the predictions are to the actual values.
When you calculate the averages of the groups like you do, you lose that interpretation. For instance, say $y = \left\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\right\}$.
Let $\hat y =\left\{3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4\right\}$ be the corresponding predictions. When you calculate the group means, you get that $\bar{\hat{y_1}} = \frac{3 + 2 + 1}{3} = 2$ and $\bar{\hat{y_2}} = \frac{6 + 5 + 4}{3} = 5$. You also get that $\bar y_1 = \frac{1+2+3}{3} = 2$ and $\bar y_2 = \frac{4, 5, 6}{3} = 5$. When you calculate the group-wise RMSE, you get zero, indicating perfect agreement. However, the predictions are not perfect!
You are seeing such divergence because the two calculations describe different facets of the predictions. RMSE describes how close or far the predictions and true values are. Your calculation describes how close or far the average predictions of groups are from average true values of that group, regardless of how good the raw predictions are.
While I see a use for calculating the RMSE of particular groups (e.g., are we better at predicting for the Americans than we are for the Canadians), I do not see a use for binning this way and comparing the averages, when so much about how good the predictions are can get lost.
